# Trouble identifing this barcode, using zbar and redlaser

Tags: barcode, zbar

So I've got this barcode (which I will attach) and I don't know how to decode it, both zbar on my desktop and redlaser on my phone cannot read it.  After a lot of googling, and reading on forums I can't find similar barcodes... Any suggestions?

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13940239/2013-04-30%2009.36.28.jpg

Sorry I realised I needed a higher repuation to post an image, here is a dropbox link

After identifing the barcode, can anyone help with zbar decoding the barcode.  I'd like do set this up so the software will decode similar barcodes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a Code 39 barcode with a 3 bar widths char gap, which reads '1004876532'. Almost any standard bar code reader should be able to read this type. [This online bar code decoder](http://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com/) was able to read a cleaned up version of the image you originally posted.

[image: code 39 barcode with a 3 bar widths char gap]

*the yellow arrows represent the 3 bar width character gaps.

Answer (score 0):

it seams to be Code_39 format, value: 1004876532